# Local Interest Point Detection using Difference of Gaussian in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift

I'm writing the code in Matlab to find interest point using DoG in the image. 
Here is the main.m:

```
imTest1 = rgb2gray(imread('1.jpg'));
imTest1 = double(imTest1);

sigma = 0.6;
k = 5;
thresh = 3;

[x1,y1,r1] = DoG(k,sigma,thresh,imTest1);
%get the interest points and show it on the image with its scale
figure(1);
imshow(imTest1,[]), hold on, scatter(y1,x1,r1,'r');
```

And the function DoG is:

```
function [x,y,r] = DoG(k,sigma,thresh,imTest)
x = []; y = []; r = [];
%suppose 5 levels of gaussian blur
for i = 1:k
    g{i} = fspecial('gaussian',size(imTest),i*sigma);
end
%so 4 levels of DoG
for i = 1:k-1
    d{i} = imfilter(imTest,g{i+1}-g{i});
end
%compare the current pixel in the image to the surrounding pixels (26 points),if it is the maxima/minima, this pixel will be a interest point
for i = 2:k-2
    for m = 2:size(imTest,1)-1
        for n = 2:size(imTest,2)-1

            id = 1;
            compare = zeros(1,27);
            for ii = i-1:i+1
                for mm = m-1:m+1
                    for nn = n-1:n+1
                        compare(id) = d{ii}(mm,nn);
                        id = id+1;
                    end
                end
            end

            compare_max = max(compare);
            compare_min = min(compare);

            if (compare_max == d{i}(m,n) || compare_min == d{i}(m,n))
                if (compare_min < -thresh || compare_max > thresh)
                    x = [x;m];
                    y = [y;n];
                    r = [r;abs(d{i}(m,n))];
                end
            end

        end
    end
end
end
```

So there's a gaussian function and the sigma i set is 0.6. After running the code, I find the position is not correct and the scales looks almost the same for all interest points. I think my code should work but actually the result is not. Anybody know what's the problem?

[image: the test image 1.jpg]
[image: the correct result for reference]

Comment: DoG is available using the MATLAB image toolbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057146/is-there-any-difference-of-gaussians-function-in-matlab --> Try this code instead of your DoG-function and see what the result is. If it is the same, then I guess the parameters used in your main.m are not chosen so that the output is the desired one. If it is different, then your DoG-function is coded wrongly.

Comment: Perfect question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832. Could you follow and upvote questions with less than 10 up votes? Thank You.